# Prove that orbits of one system are orbits of another

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

> Let $$\left\{\begin{align}
> \dot x &= x- \frac{xy}{1+\alpha x}\\
> \dot y &= -y + \frac{xy}{1+\alpha x}+\delta y^2
> \end{align} \right.$$
>   be a predator-prey model.
>
> Prove that the following polynomial system has the same orbits as the original model. $$\left\{\begin{align}
> \dot x &= x(1+\alpha x)-xy\\
> \dot y &= -(y+\delta y^2)(1+\alpha x) +xy
> \end{align} \right.$$

Could someone provide a hint?

I have tried: Let $(x(t),y(t))$ be an orbit of the second system where $x(t), y(t) >0 \quad (\forall t)$. Then I should prove that this is also an orbit of the first system. A substitution leads to $(1+\alpha \cdot x(t) ) \dot x(t) = \dot x(t)$ which seems to imply $\dot x(t) = 0$, nonsense!

I guess I should translate/manipulate the orbit $(x(t),y(t))$, but how?

Comment: It is quite obvious that the two equations don't have the same orbits (not even in the first quadrant...). But you seem to think that they should have in fact the same solutions.

Comment: @Jonas I disagree with the statement that orbits of points from first quadrant are different. Of course solutions are different, but the orbits are the same.

Comment: @Evgeny Well, certainly you don't agree that $\delta y^2=-\delta y^2$...

Comment: @Jonas Okay, let's make it clear. If we read the question literally as it was written, then yes, I agree with you, these two systems hardly seem to be equivalent in the first quadrant, you are right. To me it's obvious that the question has a typo -- the one that is very easy overlook. And I did that, I overlooked it. This is a source of disagreement. Still I think that lhf 's answer is relevant and should be expanded a bit.

Comment: @Evgeny So we agree, and so indeed I was right (the reason for my comment is only the sign since otherwise it is clearly immediate that the orbits are the same, it is simply a time change, of course only in the first and fourth quadrants).

Answer (score 2):

The vector fields in the two systems differ by a scalar multiple $1+\alpha x$.

Comment: It would be nice if you provide a reference to the statement that you use implicitly.