# Show that orbitally equivalent autonomous systems do have same orbits

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, equivalence-relations

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_conjugacy),

> Two dynamical systems on the same state space, defined by $\dot {x}=f(x)$ and $\dot {x}=g(x)$, are said to be *orbitally equivalent* if there is a positive function, $\mu :X\to \mathbb {R}$, such that $g(x)=\mu (x)f(x)$. Orbitally equivalent system differ only in the time parametrization.

I wonder why do orbitally equivalent have same orbits. Intuitively, the two systems would have the same "direction of velocity" at any given point, but this is not a mathematical proof, right?

I can not found any relating information except [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1816284/prove-that-orbits-of-one-system-are-orbits-of-another) where lhf implicitly uses this property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x=\xi(t)$ is a solution of $dx/dt=f(x)$, let $T(s)$ be a solution of $dT/ds=\mu(\xi(T(s)))$. Then $t=T(s)$ is a time reparametrization that does the trick for that particular orbit, i.e., $x=\xi(T(s))$ solves $dx/ds=g(x)$:
$$
\frac{dx}{ds}
=\frac{d}{ds} \Bigl( \xi(T(s)) \Bigr)
=\frac{d\xi}{dt}(T(s)) \cdot \frac{dT}{ds}(s)
= f(\xi(T(s))) \cdot \mu(\xi(T(s)))
=g(\xi(T(s)))
=g(x)
.
$$

Comment: What a neat way to construct the time reparametrization! I always thought that some inverse function would be involved which imposes additional constraint.

Comment: Well, strictly speaking, you only have a reparametrization, if T is a C1-diffeomorphism. But yes, the proof also works if mu has nodes.